# What is the name of the compound Sc(HCO2)3?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

I would like to know what the name of the compound $\ce{Sc(HCO2)3}$ is. I've been told that it is not *scandium hydrogen carbonite* and that it is not *scandium formate*. Any hints or suggestions about how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Note that I’ve never heard *carbonite* before.

Comment: @Jan It's very good for freezing people in!

Comment: @Jan In Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back, Han Solo is frozen in carbonite (and then subsequently defrosted in the next film).

Comment: [This](http://cccc.uochb.cas.cz/55/2/0426/) says scandium formate, both taxonomically and structurally.

Comment: Sc(HCO2)3 is scandium formate, or scandium methanoate. It cannot be anything else !

Answer (score 9):

The formula you have is definitely scandium formate. There is one of four reasons why someone (like your instructor or your online homework service) might tell you that scandium formate is wrong.

1. Someone wants you to call this compound scandium(III) formate because scandium can have multiple oxidation states.
2. Someone wants you to call this compound scandium methanoate (or scandium(III) methanoate) since methanoate is another name for the formate ion.
3. You are correct and your instructor is wrong (or your assignment software has the wrong answer keyed in).
4. There is a typo in the formula you were given.

Comment: Could be scandium bicarbonate with a typo.

Comment: Why it is not scandium bicarbonate?

Comment: @Aneek - The bicarbonate anion is $\ce{HCO3^-}$. The formula given in the question is $\ce{Sc(HCO2)3}$.

Comment: If an error did occur, and maybe recurring, what, if any, implications should a student draw? This serious issue, in my opinion, is not considered. See my answer below for possible need to check sources and actual background of my personal experience.

Comment: @BenNorris can scandium really show multiple oxidation states? AFAIK it only shows a +3 state